# Issues with PHP login script using SQLite3 Database

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite

I have a PHP login script that i use with `mysql` database and when i try using it with a `SQLite3` database i get the following error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method SQLite3Stmt::fetchArray() in C:\xampp\htdocs\xport\login.php on line 13

```
session_start();
require_once ("db.php");
$db = new MyDB();

if (!empty($_POST['log_name']) && !empty($_POST['log_password']))
{
    $records = $db->prepare('SELECT userid, regas, uemail, uname, pword FROM users WHERE uname = :uname');
    $records->bindParam(':uname', $_POST['log_name']);
    $records->execute();

    $result = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //Tried this to
    //$result = $records->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);

    if (count($result) > 0 && password_verify($_POST['pword'], $result['pword']))
    {
        $_SESSION['log_id'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['log_name'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['regas'] = $regas;
        $_SESSION['uemail'] = $uemail;
        header('Location: index.php?log_id="'.$id.'"');
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Username or password incorrect!';
    }
}
```

Please, what is wrong with this code using `SQLite3` and how can it be fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a manual (which you should read), SQLite's [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.execute.php) returns object of type `SQLite3Result`, over which you can iterate to fetch data.

So, improved part of code is:

```
$records = $db->prepare('SELECT userid, regas, uemail, uname, pword FROM users WHERE uname = :uname');
$records->bindParam(':uname', $_POST['log_name']);
$stmt_result = $records->execute();

// also remove PDO::FECTH_ASSOC as you don't use PDO
// can use SQLITE3_ASSOC or SQLITE3_BOTH or SQLITE3_NUM
$result = $stmt_result->fetchArray();
// test what you have
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code with:

`$record->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);`

it returns fatal error but when I ran code with:

`$record->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

then it ran fine and return a result object.